# window.onload set each value to 0

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
    let form = document.querySelector('#input-calculator');
    let inputs = Array.from(form.elements)
    let inputValues = inputs.map(e => e.value)
    console.log(inputValues)
    inputValues.forEach(function(item){
    var integer = parseInt(item, 10)
    integer == 0
    });
}
```

Won't set all inputs to 0 onload. I also with them to be integer, so I can add them later.

Comment: `document.querySelector` will select the _first_ matching element; use `querySelectorAll` if you want to select multiple elements.

Comment: Good practice is not to have multiple instances of one Id in a DOM at a time. Instead can use class. And 'querySelectorAll' to get all instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the values of the inputs. `==` just compares a value to another value. You need to use `=` to set them. Inputs will always have string values as inputs so every time you read the values you'll have to use `parseInt(input.value, 10)`.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const form = document.querySelector('#input-calculator');
    Array
      .from(form.elements)
      .forEach((input) => input.value = '0');
}
```